# Database error when upgrading to Assets 2.1.3

Tags: assets

I've been trying to upgrade from Assets 1.2.1 to 2.1.3 but I get this error when I click "run module updates" as the [docs explain to do.](http://docs.pixelandtonic.com/assets/installation.html) The error I receive is:

> A Database Error Occurred
> Error Number: 1054
>
> Unknown column 'file_path' in 'exp_assets'
>
> ALTER TABLE exp_assets MODIFY COLUMN file_path VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
>
> Filename: /path/to/html/third_party/assets/upd.assets.php
>
> Line Number: 403

ExpressionEngine is version 2.5.3

Comment: This looks like it might turn into a bug report... care to send an email over to support@pixelandtonic.com with some CP/FTP credentials so we can dig in and see what's going on?

Comment: @BradBell The site is on a local install, I can't push it live because it's also giving front-end errors. I'd be happy to share my screen on Skype if that's an option?

Comment: Can you shoot an email over to support@pixelandtonic.com so we can figure something out?

Comment: I sent one last night, but maybe it got buried along with other requests. Just sent another email.

Comment: Weird... not getting anything.  Not even in SPAM folder.

Comment: Maybe try brad@pixelandtonic.com?

Comment: Brad, I sent another email one from my Gmail address. Maybe this one will make it to you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The update stalled and left a few tables in the database that needed deleted. I deleted the tables and reran the install. Working fine now.

Thanks to P&T for all their support!

Comment: In case it helps anyone else... I was updating from Assets v1.2.1 to 2.3.2 and ran into the same error. The tables I needed to delete to have an error-free upgrade were `assets_folders`, `assets_sources`, `assets_files`, `assets_selections`, `assets_index_data`, and `assets_rackspace_access`. YMMV. Back up your database first!